# GLKView and double buffering

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

Reading through Apple [docs for GLKView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/glkit/glkview) it looks like the GLES rendering is single buffered when using GLKView.That's,GLKView creates one standard FBO, as well as MSAA FBO,if requested.That's it?No double buffering when using GLKView?
Now,if this is true,and  GLKView is not double buffered,can I make the default FBO setups manually using   [CAEAGLLayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/WorkingwithEAGLContexts/WorkingwithEAGLContexts.html).In this case,I can setup as many FBOs as I want and swap between them when blitting to screen?Does it make sense?

Is

```
[context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
```

call even asynchronous?

Is double buffering for GL encouraged on mobile platforms (iOS in this case) from the performance point of view?

The questions above may seem trivial,but I can't find any answers in the official docs.